# jQuery ajax request with indexed array as key string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I submit an ajax request with following data:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: BASE_URL + '/api/get/filter/',
            cache: false,
            data: {
                'search': {
                    'foo[bar]': 'foo'
                },
                'foo[bar]': 'foo'
            }
        })
```

So far so good, the data are send to the server, but when I return the $_POST var, I get following result:

```
$_POST: 
foo: 
    bar: "foo"
search: 
    foo[bar: "foo"
```

There ist something wrong with "search: foo[bar", shouldn't this be an array too?

The idea is to disable the submit of a GET Form, changing the URL by Form parameters via pushState without reloading the webpage and finally submit the data via Ajax. This works perfectly, but it does not work, as soon as I send this data inside another array key like "search" in the given example.

MORE SIMPLE QUESTION: 
- I have the following URL (with unknown get parameters): http://www.test.com/?foo[]=bar&foo[]=test&foo[bar][]=foo
How can I get all GET parameters with jQuery and send them with Ajax?

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct javascript to write `'foo[bar]'`.

Anyway, an array is an object with indexes being integers from 0 to the array length. `arr[52]` is an arrray, `obj['string']` is an object.

You should use a correct syntax instead of relying on jQuery (or server listener) attempt to make sense of your code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: BASE_URL + '/api/get/filter/',
  cache: false,
  data: {
    'search': {
      'foo': {
        'bar': 'foo'
      }
    },
    'foo':  {
      'bar': 'foo'
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a plugin called $.deparam, this should do the job: https://github.com/chrissrogers/jquery-deparam

Answer (score -1):

A json array looks like this:

```
[
    { 'foo': {
        'bar': 'foo'
        }
    }
]
```

This will make `$foo['bar'] = foo`